# using ace-jump-mode inside shell in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings

I am using *shell* in Emacs (`M-x shell`). Often, when I try to copy-paste a particular snippet of text from the output (say the output of a `ls`), I want to use ace-jump-mode to jump to a particular point on my screen but C-c+SPC seems to result to a new line and not prompt me for the head char. By using `describe-key` I get the following message:

```
C-c SPC runs the command comint-accumulate, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function. [...]
```

Why is the binding changed in the *shell* mode? In any other buffer describe-key shows the correct, anticipated binding for C-c SPC:

```
C-c SPC runs the command ace-jump-mode, which is an interactive Lisp function in `ace-jump-mode.el'.
```

How can I ensure that my ace jump bindings are not hijacked in *shell* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my standard way to resolve this behavior.
You can use it as a template for any mode:

```
(defun my-shell-hook ()
  (define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "C-c SPC") 'ace-jump-mode))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-hook)
```

Although `ace-jump-mode` seems to misbehave when in `shell`, but
that's a different problem.